# How to specify the stderr file in the bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Some bash code....
```

And when starting it with:

```
./myscript.sh
```

I would like to redirect the error into *error.err* file, and I would like to specify the name of this file (here: error.err) inside *myscript.sh* file.

(so I would like to avoid doing: `./myscript.sh 2>error.err`)

Is it possible

Thanks a lot

Comment: The linked question covers stdout as well, but its answers are trivial to adapt to ignore stdout and redirect stderr only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prepend the following line to the script

```
exec 2>error.err
```

Comment: Read the part "so I would like to avoid doing........"

Comment: @ailauli69 you put it inside the script as a line of code. An empty `exec` changes the destination of your file descriptors for the currently running process.